# Prevent words encroaching into the column break on a \twocolumn article.

Tags: two-column, text

I'm pretty new to Latex so please excuse me if there is an obvious fix, I did some googling and couldn't find a solution.

Here is a screenshot of the issue I am having.
[image: A screenshot of the issue I am having]

My preamble (most of which is copy pasted from various templates):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titlespacing\section{-5pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{-5pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{4pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\leading{13pt}
\newcommand{\no}{\noindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-15pt}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\myworries[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\title{blahhblahhh}
\author{me}

\begin{document}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX doesn't hyphenate “manned”, “smaller” and “Hayabusa” (by the way the name is spelled differently a few lines below). Try editing the offending paragraph; in an emergency, you can still input `man\-ned`, `smal\-ler` and `Haya\-busa`.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Oops, still a draft version so havent done a typo check yet!

Is there no way to force it to just move the word onto the next line if it cant hyphenate it? Manually hyphenating seems like a lot of effort, it happens frequently throughout the document

Comment: you could use `\sloppy`

Comment: why do you have a shortcut to `\noindent` ? you should almost never need that

Comment: Try `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Comment: @egreg -- `man-ned` should be used only in elizabethan poetry.  it would be entirely out of place in an astrophysical report.  i've grown very fond of `sloppypar`, although sometimes `microtype` takes care of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment so I'll comment as an answer.

Basically add hyphenation to the words. If the same word are frequently the problem you might want to set hyphenation rules for them globally (in the preamble).

```
\usepackage{hypenat}
\hyphenation{Haya-busa}
```

If there are lots of words where this happens (basically if the columns are very narrow) you can set (and reset) spacing allowance with `\sloppy` (`\fussy`).

If this also is too much work set `\sloppy` at the beginning and never reset or directly play with `\emergencystretch` (in the preamble):

```
\emergencystretch 3em
```

Basically `\sloppy` also uses `\emergencyspace`, but setting it directly allows you more control.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  if you're going to set `\emergencystretch`, do it within a local group (ending with a paragraph break) so that it doesn't persist through the rest of the document.  even better, wrap `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` around the affected paragraph.  it defines the scope properly, so you don't have to remember how.

Answer (score -1):

you also try with `\lefthyphenmin=3\righthyphenmin=3`...

Comment: You've written a number of poor answers lately. No explanation, no detail, just "try this". You should add some more substance to your answers so they may be received better.